# How to compute modulo on BigInts in JS

Tags: javascript, bigint

Given a BigInt in JS, how do you compute its modulo?

```
10n % 3 // Uncaught TypeError: can't convert BigInt to number
```

edit: the difference between this question and the one linked as similar is that this question only pertains to BigInt https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt which is fairly recent.

Comment: Use a big int for both operands - `10n % 3n`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both operands of an arithmetic operation involving a BigInt must be BigInts. In your case:

```js
// BigInt literal
10n % 3n;

// BigInt explicit conversion
10n % BigInt(3);
```